# Create LINKED SERVER to MYSQL using SSH

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2014, linked-server, sql-server-2019, ssh

**Is there any way to create a MS SQL Server Linked Server to connect to MySQL through SSH?**

I managed to connect to MySQL through SSH using other database management tools like HeidiSQL or DBeaver, however I'd like to have this setup up for SSMS. I downloaded the MySQL ODBC driver but I can't find where to setup the SSH connection

[image]

Answer (score 0):

HeidiSQL or DBeaver manage the SSH connection and not ODBC. You'll need to create your SSH connection with a port forward first.

Then test if you can connect a mysql client to the local ssh forwarded port.

Then attempt to create your linked server using ODBC to local end of the ssh forwarded port.

Comment: Thanks danblack. In my case, I managed to resolve this issue by creating a new MySQL user, configuring the ODBC connection and creating the Linked Server